# Запуск телеграм-бота на постоянную работу

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Куда выгрузить питон файл с телеграмм ботом? Он должен работать всегда, а не только когда у меня на компьютере запущен. Дайте ссылку или обьясните

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы Ваш телеграм-бот начал работать не на Ваше ПК, Вам нужна виртуальная машина, либо выделенный сервер. С последним всё сильно сложнее. Я остановлюсь на виртуальной машине.

Для примера, возьму [Y.cloud](https://cloud.yandex.ru/). Создайте личный кабинет, и начать пользоваться пробным периодом (если он ещё остался). Минимальная виртуалка стоит примерно 300 рублей в месяц. Но она будет очень слабой: 1 ядро и 1 ГБ оперативы. Виртуалка помощнее обойдётся в 500-600 рублей в месяц.

Для виртуальной машины выбирается операционная система. Советую использовать unix-подобную систему. Я обычно пользуюсь Ubuntu. После этого она запускается. Вам предоставляется статический или динамический ip-адрес, по которому Ваша машина будет доступна.

Для того, чтобы зайти на машину, Вам потребуется консоль (bash, shell) из которой, с помощью команды ssh, Вы сможете подключиться к удалённой машине. Перед Вами откроется консоль ровно такая же, как на вашем рабочем ПК. Вы сможете делать всё то же самое, что и на рабочей машине.

Эта виртуальная машина будет работать в том числе, когда Ваш ПК будет выключен.